# Why does getStackTrace() return different addresses in this Java code?

Tags: java, stack-trace

I have the following simple java code :

```
try { -
    ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("TheBatchFile.bat", "Argument1", "Argument2");
    pb.directory(new File("/path/to/working/dir"));
    Process p = pb.start();
    p.waitFor();

} catch ( IOException e) {

    System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace());
    System.out.println("Heres some line");
    System.out.println(e.getStackTrace() ) ;

    System.out.println (" Print-Statement After StackTrace");
}
```

And then when I run it twice in a row , it will  return different results. Here's output:

```
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@fe64b9
Heres some line
[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@186db54
 Print-Statement After StackTrace
```

I was curious about what is going on here - why is it that, even though I already compiled it, and I run the same code, it will still give different results for the `getStackTrace()`

Comment: `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` and `e.getStackTrace()` refer to different objects or are dynamically generated, therefore they are saved on different memory adresses (may even contain different information?), that would be the easiest explanation.

Comment: Those are not "addresses", they are the object's identity hash, which is more or less a random value

Comment: Oh, `fe64b9` and `186db54` are not the memory adresses of the `e.getStrackTrace()` and `Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()` object? Then I take my comment back.

Comment: @MaximilianGerhardt https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString-- ...

Comment: Don't post images of text here. Complete waste of your time and our bandwidth. Post the text. You do not need to take pictures of stack traces.

Comment: @EJP - granted - thanks, I fixed this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `getStackTrace()` method is defined in the `Throwable` class (the superclass of all `Exception`s) as:

```
public StackTraceElement[] getStackTrace() {
    return getOurStackTrace().clone();
}
```

So each time it is invoked (whether using `Exception#getStackTrace()` or using `Thread#getStackTrace()`), it will eventually return a new object. Hence a new hash code is expected to be printed.